# how to set checkbox checked and do it onclick together?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

My code is only let checkbox checked,I want it also do onclick event.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list" id="mycheckbox"  onclick="check_marker(this)" />
document.getElementById(mycheckbox).checked = true;//I want also do onclick event.
    function check_marker(input_var){
    var carId;
    carId = input_var.id;
    alert(carId);
}
```

Comment: I also want to let it return `this`

Comment: did you make an onlick event to check the checkbox? It would be redundant as a checkbox already does this. I don't understand the question really. Please include the code to your check_marker() function.

Comment: I just want function do,I don't click the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made through javascript do not trigger handlers.  You will need to call it yourself after making the change:

http://jsfiddle.net/F2J37/

```
var cb = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");

cb.checked = true;
cb.onclick();  // call the click handler directly
```