# submit form when checkbox is checked AJAX / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I wanting to submit the filter form when any of the checkboxes' are checked. Have looked at multiple forums and cant seen to get the answer. Also with the current code when i uncheck the input box it passes empty value. All in the same file. Go easy i am new :) . I want to see the parameter in the url , so i can pass value to this page from other pages and select the appropriate checkbox on load

```
**TEST.PHP**




<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">Advance Ajax Product Filters in PHP</h2>
           <br />
           <form action="" id="filter">
           <div class="col-md-3"> 
                   <div class="list-group">
                    <h3>LEVEL</h3>
                    <div style="height: 180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                        <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(carcolor) FROM car";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);

                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            foreach($result as $row)
                            {
                        ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor()" class="color" name="color" value="<?= $row['carcolor']; ?>"/>
                        <label><?php echo $row['carcolor']; ?></label>
                        <?php
                            }
                        }
    
                        else {
                            echo "No data Found";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="col-md-9">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

function filtercolor() {
    var color = $('input:checkbox[name="color"]:checked').map(function(){return    this.value;}).get().join('|'); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'test.php', 
        data:"color=" + color, 
        type: "GET", 
        success: function(html) { 
            alert('form submited'); 
        }, 
    }); 
} 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have not add jquery link

Comment: any error showing

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI - on clicking the color input , looking at the console there is no error, also the alert pops up 'form submitted' , so its working but the url is now showing the parameter test.php?color=red , its just as test.php

Comment: use ajax post instead of get

Comment: but that wont show in the url , if i pass red color from another page to test.php it wont work ?

Comment: it won't work means, is it value coming to php page

Comment: For work if checkbox is checked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735337/how-to-set-checkbox-checked-and-do-it-onclick-together

Comment: with POST its only showing test.php with GET it will show as test.php?color=red, is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function filtercolor(checkBox) {
  let checkBox_val = checkBox.value;
  alert(checkBox_val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> 0 </span>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor(this)" class="color" value="0"/> <br>
<span> 1 </span>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor(this)" class="color" value="1"/> <br>
<span> 2 </span>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor(this)" class="color" value="2"/> <br>
<span> 3 </span>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor(this)" class="color" value="3"/> <br>
<span> 4 </span>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filtercolor(this)" class="color" value="4"/>
```